# Java app as windows service with database connection

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, service, sessionfactory

i'm trying to run java application as a windows service with tomcat 7. in this application i have database connection to MySql with Hibernate. when i ran the tomcat it stops in this line:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

i have all the necessary jars of the hibernate in WEB-INF\lib directory.
when run this app from the eclipse its running fine.
this is the run.bat file:

```
cd "c:\Users\sl300\Project\temp3\build\classes"
temp3.exe //IS//temp3 ^
--Install="c:\Users\sl300\Project\temp3\build\classes\temp3.exe" ^
--Description="My Watcher Service" ^
--Jvm=auto ^
--Classpath="c:\Users\sl300\Project\temp3\build\classes" ^
--StartMode=jvm --StartClass=ServiceControl ^
--StartMethod=windowsService ^
--StartParams=start ^
--StopMode=jvm ^
--StopClass=ServiceControl ^
--StopMethod=windowsService ^
--StopParams=stop ^
--LogPath="c:\Users\sl300\Project\temp3\logs" ^
--StdOutput=auto ^
--StdError=auto 
temp3w //MS//
```

what i need to do to make this work?

Comment: No log files available? I bet hibernate cannot find its configuration... do you use embedded tomcat?

Comment: i got this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought. The hinternate classes are not available in the classpath and I guess the tomcat classes neither. You have to rework that file if you do *not* use embedded tomcat. Look at `tomcat/bin` folder and the corresponding startup scripts.

Comment: Ok i moved all the jars to "c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib" where all the tomcat jars are and changed this in the run.bat file:"--Classpath="c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib" ^" and its still give me the same error

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer. Try that. tomcat does also have the bootstrap classpath pointing to JARs in `tomcat/bin`.

Comment: i'm not shore what you want me to do. i tried to move the jars to tomcat/bin and still i get this error. i have bootstrap.jar in this directory but i cant open it.

Comment: you have to exactly follow the installation guide provided by tomcat. Btw: What is `temp3.exe`?

Comment: temp3.exe is tomcat7.exe

Answer (score 0):

A detailed manual on how to configure Tomcat as a Windows service is available at [tomcat.apache.org](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html). This should solve your problems.

It is provided in the [Windows specific ZIP downloads](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) only, not the generic ones.

EDIT: This is not an answer, but I did want to stop chatting in the *coments* section:

1. Why is your `temp3.exe` located in the folder `...build/classes`, this does not make sense to me?
2. Why did you rename it to `temp3.exe`?

Comment: thx but i did find a way to do this. i exported my project to a jar file and insert the tomcat.exe inside with the run.bat file. thank you!!